Transitons doesn't work with StatefulShellRoute in go_router package
This is the official example that demonstrates how to setup nested navigation using a BottomNavigationBar, where each bar item uses its own persistent navigator, i.e. navigation state is maintained separately for each item. This setup also enables deep linking into nested pages.
https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/stateful_shell_route.dart
Now I want to add CustomTransitionPage between pages in the bottom navigation bar, so I used pageBuilder instead of builder, but it didn't work.
This is the full code after adding the CustomTransitionPage

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'root');
final _sectionANavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'sectionANav');

void main() {
  runApp(NestedTabNavigationExampleApp());
}

class NestedTabNavigationExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  NestedTabNavigationExampleApp({super.key});

  final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
    initialLocation: '/a',
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
        pageBuilder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
          return CustomTransitionPage(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: ScaffoldWithNavBar(navigationShell: navigationShell),
            transitionsBuilder:
                (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
              return FadeTransition(
                opacity: animation,
                child: child,
              );
            },
          );
        },
        branches: <StatefulShellBranch>[
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _sectionANavigatorKey,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: '/a',
                pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage(
                  key: state.pageKey,
                  child: const RootScreen(label: 'A'),
                  transitionsBuilder:
                      (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                    return FadeTransition(
                      opacity: animation,
                      child: child,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: '/b',
                pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage(
                  key: state.pageKey,
                  child: const RootScreen(label: 'B'),
                  transitionsBuilder:
                      (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                    return FadeTransition(
                      opacity: animation,
                      child: child,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: '/c',
                pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage(
                  key: state.pageKey,
                  child: const RootScreen(label: 'C'),
                  transitionsBuilder:
                      (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                    return FadeTransition(
                      opacity: animation,
                      child: child,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

/// Builds the "shell" for the app by building a Scaffold with a
/// BottomNavigationBar, where [child] is placed in the body of the Scaffold.
class ScaffoldWithNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScaffoldWithNavBar({
    required this.navigationShell,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key ?? const ValueKey<String>('ScaffoldWithNavBar'));

  /// The navigation shell and container for the branch Navigators.
  final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: navigationShell,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Section A'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.work), label: 'Section B'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.tab), label: 'Section C'),
        ],
        currentIndex: navigationShell.currentIndex,
        onTap: (int index) => _onTap(context, index),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onTap(BuildContext context, int index) {
    navigationShell.goBranch(
      index,
      initialLocation: index == navigationShell.currentIndex,
    );
  }
}

/// Widget for the root/initial pages in the bottom navigation bar.
class RootScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const RootScreen({
    required this.label,
    super.key,
  });

  final String label;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Root of section $label'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Screen $label'),
      ),
    );
  }
}



It is possible to animate the transitions, but you will have to make the animations/transitions yourself and you won't be using CustomTransitionsPage for it.
What you're going to have to do is pass a function to StatefulShellRoute.navigatorContainerBuilder which has a context, StatefulNavigationShell and List<Children> (which are the branch navigators) for arguments.
You'd want to build the ScaffoldWithNavBar with that instead, passing in the StatefulNavigationShell and List<Children.>. Then you'd want to do something like this in the build function:
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: BranchAnimator(
      currentIndex: navigationShell.currentIndex,
      children: children,
    ),
    ...


And the BranchAnimator can be as simple or as complicated as you want it to be. The most basic (no animation) would be a simple stack:
class BranchAnimator extends StatelessWidget {
  const BranchAnimator({super.key, required this.currentIndex, required this.children});

  final int currentIndex;
  final List<Widget> children;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: children.mapIndexed(
        (int i, Widget child) {
          return Opacity(  /// <<---- here
            opacity: i == currentIndex ? 1 : 0,
            child: IgnorePointer(
              ignoring: i != currentIndex,
              child: TickerMode(
                enabled: i == currentIndex,
                child: child,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}

That basically replicates the default behaviour - if you want to actually perform animations then you'll need to modify where the <<---- here is in the code above - either by making that opacity into an AnimatedOpacity or something more complicated if you want a more custom animation. There are many different ways you could go about this, depending on what type of animation you wanted and how complicated you wanted it to be. Your first step would probably be to make the BranchAnimator into a stateful widget, keep the last index so that you could know what type of animation to draw, and probably mix in TickerProviderStateMixin after which performing the animation should be fairly similar to how you would have implemented a CustomTransitionPage.
There's an example of this in the same repository you linked to that does a basic animation on the opacity and size: https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/others/custom_stateful_shell_route.dart.
